# Add a tag stats per user view

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges

I'd like to have a stats view for the tags I've participated.

The same we have now for general tag stats, but at the user level.

It should show per each tag you've got on your user profile the amount upvotes in addition to the amount of answers (or have a switch/tab that let you change between answers and upvotes).

Of course this can be obtained via the data dump, but the data gets a month old each month.

Comment: As an alternative: Show my values in the general tag stats even if I'm not one of the top answerers.

Comment: @Vinko this used to be the case, it was recently removed due to caching issues. See my question for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Firefox, you could use this [Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623). It adds a link next to each tag in the tags section which when clicked totals all the votes for a that tag.

Here's a screenshot showing a completed query (for eclipse-rcp) and one in progress (for java):

[image: tags query screenshot]

Comment: As much as I hate Greasemonkey as an answer for anything, I give this +1 for win.  I'm actually going to go install GM for the first time just because of this, because I've been *dying* for better stats access around here.

Comment: @womp let me know what you think of it. I'm pretty new to javascript and GM, so all feedback is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is different from what is already available?

You have all the tags you participated in on your profile already with counts next to them of the questions and answers in total, and by clicking on the tag it shows you only the questions and answers you have provided for that particular tag.

Personally I see no need for more then that.

Comment: I'm thinking about the upvote count, to see how far from a badge I am in each.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a query for this using the data dump. Here's your top 10 tags:

```
  348   php
  316   python
  251   perl
  233   subjective
  216   java
  195   sql
  174   mysql
  157   c#
  150   regex
  148   .net
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although the idea is to have a current count.

Comment: I understand. :)