# Clarify wording for tag-based badges

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges

In testing my Greasemonkey script for counting votes for a tag (to address this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug)), I noticed a discrepancy in the results.

The wording for the [tag badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) is:

> As you use Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions, you'll earn badges, which appear on your user page and in your user card.
>
> ...
>
> Tag-based badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. If enough upvotes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

This wording implies (to me at least) that votes for both questions and answers count towards the total for a tag-badge. However when checking my script's results I noticed that the total count for maven-2 as measured by the script comes to **259**, whereas the count on the stats page is **250**. I have **9** votes from 2 questions on maven-2, so it appears that only answers actually count towards the total (note I've excluded community wiki results from the search, see example query below).

Here is [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A123582+%5Bmaven-2%5D+wiki%3A0) I've used as the basis for my count:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A123582+%5Bmaven-2%5D+wiki%3A0

*Can either the wording on the page be changed to clarify that only answers count, or the processing changed to include question votes?*

Answer (score 2):

I think adding the text "on your answers" is a minimal and reasonable response to this request.  E.g. (emphasis added):

> Tag-based badges are awarded for
>   participating in non community-wiki
>   questions with particular tags. If
>   enough upvotes are earned **on your answers**
>   in a tag –
>   any tag – the badge will be
>   automatically created and awarded.