# Show badges earned within the tag list in the user profile

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, profile-page

When I'm curious about which tags might be about to earn me another badge, it would be useful for the user profile to show the *current* "badge level" for the tags.

If I look at the bottom of the user profile where it's got tags and badges listed, the system clearly has all the information available - and I *could* just look through each tag and see whether I'd already got a badge for it or not. It would be simpler if the tags just showed the gold or silver badge icon "inline" though in the list of tags, just to the left of the tag name.

Comment: New meta tag is needed: `features-useful-to-only-Jon-Skeet`.

Comment: Jon, if you are bored and need more entertainment, I suggest filling the first page with 35 Jon Skeet accounts instead of looking for badges. You already have, WOW! MORE THAN A THOUSAND (:-O) badges and that's why it's hard to search in them. :)

Comment: like you need more badges.  i don't need no stinking badges. :)

Answer (score 8):

There is only one badge to care about: [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta)

And you will never get it! :-}

Comment: I want to upvote but I really can't since I have the same problem too :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: you cannot fight the truth. Swallow the pill and accept it! First step to get over it, is to upvote this answer. Trust me...

Comment: I don't think "the pill" is suitable for me ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad: you can chose between red and blue

Comment: I have a Beta badge **:P**

Answer (score 5):

I've updated my [Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623) to modify the blue rectangle to look like a badge (complete with gold/silver circle) for those tags that a badge has been awarded for.

To find out how close you are for other tags, you can click the triangle that's been added next to the tag to find the total votes for that tag (assuming you're not on the leaderboard for a tag in which case it's obviously simpler just to look there).

[image: skeet tags]

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about something like this?

> [image: all your tags belong to me]

It'd go with the levelling up mindset behind the rep and the badges. You'd be able to see the levels and work out which one you need to cast the potion of alchemy on in order to go from silver to gold.

Sounds like a feature that would be useful for that single percent of users that are Jon Skeet.

Comment: -1 for Green Lantern. Couldn't you use someone cool instead like Magneto?

Comment: @Welbog: it's no lantern. Get some glasses!

Comment: Yes, I mean something like that - although preferably integrated into the badge background colour. I don't think I'm the only person who would find it useful, although I'd find it more useful than most, certainly :)

Comment: If it's not Green Lantern, then -1 for making me think it was Green Lantern. I hate that guy.

Comment: It's a green laser focussing on Green Lantern.

Comment: Okay, original image was of KR GL with the power of the ring shining on the tags. Updated it to reflect the background tag colours instead.

Comment: Aaahhh! Can't upvote edit! It hurts so much.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant by "integrated into the badge background colour" although it's interesting. I meant to include the badge icon just to the left of the text, but still within the existing badge background.

Comment: @Jon You know what you have to do here, crack open Paint and have at.