# How close am I to a silver C++ badge on SO?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO Badge Progress Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report)

I want to check how close I am to the C++ silver badge at Stack Overflow. Is there any way to check it?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165520/prasoon-saurav) is my Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: Somebody will be along in a minute to link to the GreaseMonkey script that does this.

Comment: Back in October 2009, it would have been 399 away. http://stackql.net/default.aspx?qid=1997

Comment: Good question, I would also like to know this for a number of other tags.

Comment: The slow way is to select the tag off your profile page and count up the up-votes manually from the list of posts it shows you.

Comment: @ChristF: Already done that :-D . Count is >400 already but I have not received the badge yet.

Comment: The script (or whatever) that awards the badge doesn't run that often. I got over 400 up-votes here on meta for "discussion" and it took over a day for the badge to be awarded. Be patient. Also make sure you haven't counted any question up votes.

Comment: And only non-wiki count. So if you've got 300 of them from "What colour shoes should I buy, as a C++ developer" they won't count.

Comment: @Prasoon It's more fun when they arrive out of the blue - I was particularly pleased when this one http://stackoverflow.com/badges/158/stl arrived without warning.

Comment: @Marc: Who needs shoes for living in the basement?

Comment: Yeah I think I counted the question up votes too. Still some way to go.:-)

Comment: @Neil: Yeah you are right. I was also suprised to see my "Guru" badge without any warning. ;-)

Comment: @Marc: _What colour shoes should I buy, as a C++ developer_. ROFL, you made my day :-D

Answer (score 2):

As ChrisF commented, here's a [Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623) that will tell you how many votes you have in a particular tag.

To answer your question directly I count you currently have **344** upvotes for non community-wiki posts.

Note: to do this I tweaked the script to work on your profile page (normally the script exits unless viewing the current user's profile page to minimise spurious requests to the server). If you install the script and are logged in you would be able to count the upvotes by clicking the triangle next to the c++ tag on the profile page.

Answer (score 1):

This is an anti-answer... but the stats page totally used to show you all the time and where you were relative to the top people - what happened to that?  They took it out... why?

Comment: SQL timeouts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/bug-in-rep-statistics-display/18353#18353