# How are gold badges given for a particular tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, tags

I have a bit of confusion about this. I thought a gold badge is given after you get 1000 up votes in a tag for example C#, Java, PHP, etc.

I saw **[this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded)** (today) with only 476 upvotes for C# tag and he was given a gold badge in C# tag and elsewhere I saw **[this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz)** with 764 upvotes in PHP tag but still no gold badge.

What is the criteria for this if it is not what I thought, that is 1000 upvotes?

Or is there a query I can run (in Stack Exchange data explorer) to determine the total votes earned by a user in the specified tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice [greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623) that shows you the total upvotes per tag you got.

Answer (score 4):

The **× nnn** after the tag in the **Tags** section is not how many votes they have, but how many answers they've given for questions with that tag.

Comment: Then how to determine how many votes have been there for a tag?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&sort=stats&pagesize=50 Replace the `tagnames` value and the `pagesize` to get other tags and more results. Though don't go too high with the `pagesize`.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks but it does not tell total upvotes a user has got in specified tag.

Comment: @user If you look in the stats page for the given tag, the gray number under the all time section is the number of up votes that person has recieved.

Comment: @ChrisF: The pagesize value doesn't seem to do anything. I always get 20 results no matter what I put there.

Answer (score 2):

You need total of 1,000 *score* (upvotes - downvotes) and not just upvotes.

Now you can directly see the actual score of particular tag for any user.

Just go to [it's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) -> go to [tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded?tab=tags). Here the score for particular tag is available before tag name. Hover on it for more details. See this for example:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here in the end. Thanks all :)

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/139

Comment: there's a question on interesting queries here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer