# Top [tag] answerers always include current user

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, top-users

I was taking a look at the [stats for the Rails tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/stats) and saw this:
[image]

If you notice my user is last in this list. I was pretty surprised since I didn't participate for a while so I double checked, and it seems that the current user is always in these tops.

I checked with someone else (hellvinz) and it also appeared in the top:
[image]

When you're not logged in you don't see hellvinz nor marcgg:
[image]

So maybe this data is only here to show your advancement compared to other users, but it is quite misleading to display it as if the current user was in the top. Maybe using some other color, more white space or displaying some kind of break between the top and the current user would do the trick better.

[image]
*(you guys can figure out something prettier ^^)*

Comment: Is this a re-introduction of an old feature?  I'm sure it used to be like this.  Anyway, I think you should retag this to `[feature-request]`.

Comment: @Andy Actually, it used to simply not display you if you weren't in the top 20. Now, if you're in the top 20 you'll be where you're supposed to be, but if you're under it then you'll just be appended as a 21st entry (within 30 days only applies if you have a post made within 30 days).

Comment: @Grace, that was the behaviour until the re-introduction of the feature.  But this feature existed a while ago.  See Jeff's answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug)

Comment: @andy: retagged

Comment: @Andy I see. That's well before my time, then. As long as I had known it, it never showed you until they made the new tag pages and knowing your score was important.

Comment: @marcgg: +1, I agree that separation is a good idea for clarification that you aren't necessarily one of the top answerers in a tag.

Comment: Ill look at adding a separator, this used to be a huge performance hog, but some db refactoring made it possible to bring this feature back

Comment: "When you're logged in"? Surely you mean the opposite?

Comment: @andres: yes, corrected now

Comment: thanks @waffles, looking forward to it

Comment: Duplicate (but I can't vote to close because of the bounty): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73038/show-top-users-rank

Answer (score 13):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

But yeah, some kind of separator would be nice. I was confused at first too.

Comment: It would also be nice to see where we rank. It looks as if I'm right below the last in that list, [but I threw together a query to dispel my delusions](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/550/tag-leaderboard-for-answers).

Answer (score 7):

They do the same with medal tallies at Olympic games: [here's an Australian example](http://www.foxtel.com.au/vancouver2010/sports/medal-tally/default.htm). It lists the top nine at the Vancouver 2010 Winter Olympics, and then Australia in 14th.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my mockup I put up on the [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73038/show-top-users-rank):

Maybe just put a line above the viewing user, like so:

[image: Line Above User]