# Show top users rank

Tags: feature-request, top-users

Regarding the top user pages, I really like the feature of showing the current user (i.e. you) at the bottom if not in the top 20. But that can be misleading. I call this the **woohoo-I-made-the-top-X-wait-no-I-didn't** syndrome. The usual format I see for top X+1 lists is to have the ranking next to it, so that on a page like [C# Top Users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) you'd see:

```
 1.    34.8k 6.8k Jon Skeet
 2.    19.3k   5k Marc Gravell
 ...
 20.    2.5k  846 Henk Holterman
 20301.    6   13 MPelletier
```

Now I see myself as 21st, which is obviously wrong, but having the numbering somewhere would be nice.

EDIT:

As it is right now it's double the confusion if you're at the bottom of both lists, "Last x Days" and "All Time".

EDIT.1:

Alternative, less verbose format:

```
 34.8k 6.8k Jon Skeet
 19.3k   5k Marc Gravell
 ...
 2.5k   846 Henk Holterman
-------------------------------
    6    13 MPelletier (#20301)
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe just put a line above the viewing user, like so:

[image]

Comment: See my EDIT.1. I like a dashed horizontal line, but a red line can work too.

Comment: @MPelletier, edited.

Comment: I can't vote you up twice. Don't try. :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's some way to make it more obvious that you're not actually 21st, but I don't think there's enough space to add a whole new column for the rank index, particularly since it's almost entirely superfluous; that page is already crammed full of data

Comment: Solid point. Maybe not making the counts 300% of the regular text size would help

Comment: @Mpelletier I think it looks much better at 200% anyway, actually, so that might work

Comment: I'd settle for a nice dotted or dashed `HR` between top 20 and one self.

Comment: See my other suggestion. Much lighter (and still very compatible with 200%).