# Show top user rank

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, top-users

I have search to find top user as different way like :

- Top user of Specific Country
- Top User base on Profile View
- Top User base on Technology

I am able to check all above query result in [Data StackExchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=top+user) and i am okay with that
result.

But i am bit confusing about getting a `Rank`. I got [Top User Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow/topusers) but i am not able to see my rank or i don't know how to see Index Rank in that link.

`(i.e Chintan khetiya Rank-1000 From -India)`

They are providing `User id,web site,Reputation and other info` but i am not able to see Index OR Rank Field in result page.

While searching in Meta i got [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73038/show-top-users-rank) but i am not getting how to follow that answer.

So , Is it possible to see our Ranking Or Index ?

Thank you for read my query and use your valuable time to solve my bit confusion.

Comment: [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Mod [boltclocks a unicorn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) has this link in his profile:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27163/top-users-singapore

I have updated it for India:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/124452

This will list all users from India by rank.
Note this will also show users from Indiana

Comment: Thanks for reply, but unlucky my name is not available in the  query result.I have run the query without any changes but don't know what is cause.Let me know if you have any idea. Again thanks.+1 for you.

Comment: @chintankhetiya it's because your location is not India! it is Rajkot. How ever even when I search Rajkot only I can not seem to find you. I guess we must wait for a more well versed developer