# Top users are showing incorrectly

Tags: support, top-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top [tag] answerers always include current user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65808/top-tag-answerers-always-include-current-user)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598/jjnguy) user has 1949 score in java and, still I can't see him in top user's list ,

See here
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is only upto 20 users, and the last one (21th) is always **you**, for your reference.

That means even he is above you, it won't show up in the list because, he is not in top 20 yet (20th user - axtavt is 1966 at the moment)

Here is how it display for me.

[image]

Comment: My Mistake while interpreting .