# Minor Defect on top tag users when tied for 20th

Tags: bug, top-users

I realize this is minor, since the number of users this affects at any time is going to be extremely small, but when I'm logged in the [Top SQL Answerers page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/topusers) for the last 30 days I see that me and Justin are tied for 20th however when I look at it when logged out Justin disappears. I guess I won the tie breaker

**Logged In**

[image]

**Logged Out**

[image: Logged Out]

**Please note** this is not the issue when people don't understand why they see [themselves in the bottom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84995/top-users-are-showing-incorrectly) of the list (21st) in the unranked position

Comment: possible duplicate of [Top \[tag\] answerers always include current user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65808/top-tag-answerers-always-include-current-user) and [Top users are showing incorrectly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84995/top-users-are-showing-incorrectly)

Comment: @waiwai933 nope that's not it. I'm **above** Justin not below when logged in. When I'm not logged (or another user like yourself) I show up as expected

Comment: My first reaction was "well, you got the same score with fewer answers, so you had a better average score per answer, which was probably the tiebreaker." However, when I loaded the page just now, I saw Justin at the bottom and no trace of you at all.

Comment: @PopularDemand That's weird I just logged out to confirm and saw myself again... maybe there's no tiebreaking logic at all and the tiebreaker is non-deterministic.

Comment: That is my current working theory. (The previous statement is not meant to imply that I spent a lot of time thinking about this, and should not be taken as proof that I did.)