# Why is Adam Lear showing up as "top user" this week, by default when 0 users earned any reputation?

Tags: support, bug, reputation-leagues

For example [Stack Exchange Leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) says that Adam is the #1 user of the week on Augur (scroll to the bottom of the page):

> [image: week]

But if you click there are no users:

> [image: no users]

Same behavior can be found on other communities. What’s going on here? On which principle top user is selected if nobody earns a reputation, or several users earn the same amount of the reputation?

Comment: [Reputation by week in Augur](https://augur.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) shows, all of them received 0 reputation yet.

Comment: Probably because Adam sets up the sites and is usually user #1 on sites. It was all an evil plan to have his picture shown when no one has earned reputation yet. Mwuahahaha. (But the behavior for a tie is [undefined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140258).)

Comment: I was *wondering* who took over being user #1 ... ;p

Comment: This is currently the case on Constructed Languages too, even though Adam has earned 0 reputation on that site apart from the 100 association bonus and the 1 default bonus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When no users have earned reputation on a site for the time frame, the behavior is the same [undefined behavior that determines ties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140258) and any random user could appear there. However, the undefined behavior tends to prefer just selecting the user on the site with Id number 1. That tends to be Adam pretty often, as he usually sets up new sites these days and is often the first user to create a profile on them. But other users who have been the first sometimes appear in those lists, too. And some sites display just some random user on the site that I frankly have no slightest clue how it chose.

We could probably figure out a way to display an anonymous user icon there when there are no qualifying users yet, but the work is probably not as easy as we all think it is. Plus, the downside isn't all that noticeable and the effect disappears as soon as someone on the site earns some new reputation. The priority for fixing this is extremely low, to the point that we may never do so.

Comment: I suggest to display Community user (id = -1) in this case.

Comment: Thanks for writing this answer! However I'm confused by: "tends to prefer just selecting the user on the site with Id number 1" .... You mean the algorithm is random, but with a bias towards choosing user #1? That seems like a bug! I agree with the suggestion by @αλεχολυτ and I don't see why it should be so hard to do something like: `IF max(user.points_this_week) = 0, THEN display userID(-1)`

Comment: @user1271772 The behavior is undefined, which means anything could happen. In most cases, UserId of 1 was displayed, but not in all cases. And as I said, I don't know how complex it would be to do that. It's quite possible it'd be more work than it is worth. Those leagues run on some *pretty old* code.

Comment: @user1271772 It will be whatever order SQL server returns the rows in with something like "select top N where XYZ orderby rep" that will depend on the order the rows are stored on disk.

Comment: @IanRingrose Can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: @user1271772 No I can't explain how SQL databases work in a comment, but there are many books on SQL you could read.