# Bounty limit still 100 after deleting answer

Tags: bug, bounties

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep) states that if you have answered a question and start a bounty on that question, the minimum bounty is set to 100.

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23018444/1185053), answered it, deleted my answer (because the solution didn't work) and the bounty limit is still 100.

Is this still by design or is this a bug?

If it is by design, then what is the motivation of this? I understand not wanting to [hack the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack) but applying this to deleted questions seems to not fit with that.

Comment: Answers can be undeleted.

Comment: And answers can be written/copy pasted... surely it shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: @dav_i I don't think this is a bug, but rather an intentional design decision.  The system doesn't know the difference between an answer that was deleted because it didn't work and an answer that was deleted for another reason.  Someone could answer a question, delete the answer, post the bounty for 50, then undelete their answer, rendering the minimum of 100 moot.  I'm not saying I agree or disagree with this, but just that I doubt it is a bug.  If you want to change the current behavior, I think you should change this to a feature request and explain why the behavior should be changed.

Comment: This was a deliberate change in response to this question: [Undocumented increase in minimum bounty value?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116476/undocumented-increase-in-minimum-bounty-value)