# Report on number of votes that you got on each tag

Tags: feature-request, voting, statistics, tag-badges

It would be nice to have a report showing how many up and downvotes you got in each tag. For example:

```
java: 134 upvotes, 10 downvotes
perl: 100 upvotes, 8 downvotes
hibernate: 50 upvotes, 4 downvotes
```

- It will be easy for somebody or
  yourself to quickly check what you're
  good at and your main areas of interest.
- You will be able to check how close you are of
  getting a tag badge ("Earned N votes
  for answers in the X tag").

The report could filter out the tags where you got less than, say, 50 votes.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/display-statistics-have-subject-badges-for-accepted-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20606/add-a-tag-stats-per-user-view

Comment: @Gnome, @ChriF - that's interesting, thanks. But my proposal here is to integrate this solution to the site rather than relying on custom tools or scripts. Think of somebody that comes from careers.stackoverflow.com looking for potential new hires and wants to quickly check what a person is good at in SO. It would be nice if this information was provided by the site itself, instead of being retrievable with a custom tool/script only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft [custom queries](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:123266%20%5bjava%5d&tab=votes) if there are particular tags you want to [show off](https://stackoverflow.com/search).  (And there's probably only a handful of singles or combinations you would, right?)  Include them in the bio area of your profile or elsewhere.

For the purpose of showing off proficiency, [tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) are just as accurate as the raw counts that you propose.

Checking your tag badge progress can now be done with a [custom tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43421/rep-reports-lead-to-lost-reputation-recovery); we just need someone to write it.

Comment: You'll only need to write something to extract the tags and CW status from the question ID. I however don't see any "SO-friendly" way other than blatantly leeching the entire HTML in. Is there some Ajax API?

Comment: @BalusC: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-stack-overflow-api-reference

Comment: There's only one API which returns the specific question and that's a RSS (XML) feed and it lacks information about the tags and CW status. There's no JSON API which returns a specific question. Besides, SO apparently has a time limit on the amount of requests from the same IP and this is imo a showstopper. It would take too long.